# Why Azure WebJob cannot connect to Azure SQL saying "Storage account is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS'. Supported types are 'General Purpose'?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

So I have an Azure Web app, it's an ASP.NET MVC app with Entity Framework. It uses an Azure SQL database. I need to periodically (once a day) poll to financial market rate numbers and insert it int the database. I created two WebJobs for the two market rate polls (one needs to run after market open, the other is after market close), and scheduled them.

For testing I'm triggering them through the Azure portal manually, and I get a following error in the logs:

```
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Storage account 'blabla' is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS'. Supported types are 'General Purpose'
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage.StorageAccountExtensions.AssertTypeOneOf(IStorageAccount account, StorageAccountType[] types)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageAccountProvider.<CreateAndValidateAccountAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageAccountProvider.<TryGetAccountAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostConfigurationExtensions.<CreateJobHostContextAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<InitializeHostAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<CallAsyncCore>d__37.MoveNext()
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Call(MethodInfo method)
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: ERR ]    at MarketRatePreviousCloseWebJob.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Csaba\Documents\BlablaSrc\MarketRatePreviousCloseWebJob\Program.cs:line 20
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[08/25/2018 22:28:43 > a6e3be: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

I cannot make a sense of this. The SQL Azure database is kinda normal one, some of the tables have blob columns, but not the MarketRates table.
The code which tries to access the database:

```
string connectionString = "Copy of the the Azure SQL connection string";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string selectStatement = "SELECT MAX(Id) FROM BlaBla.dbo.MarketRates";
SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
var id = (int)selectCmd.ExecuteScalar();
sqlConnection.Close();

string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO BlaBla.dbo.MarketRates(Id, Type, Rate, Date) " +
    "VALUES(@Id, @Type, @Rate, @Date)";
SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection);

var now = DateTime.Now;
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.Float);
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
insertCmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = id + 1;
insertCmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = rateType;
insertCmd.Parameters["@Rate"].Value = rate;
insertCmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = now.Date;

sqlConnection.Open();
insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Is Blabla is a database name? Could you try removing the `Blabla.dbo.MarketRates` in `select` and `insert` query.

Comment: Yes, "Blabla" is the database name (obviously not exactly that, I want to protect the actual app's identity). I executed other codes from a remote Visual Studio opened up remotely on that Azure SQL database, and in those scripts the "Blabla.dbo.*" table notation seemed to work well. If the error is in the SQL statement, I wonder why I don't get any more localized error pointing towards that.

Comment: I saw you already following this issue in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1067#issuecomment-416001562).Did you able to find which line you are getting this error? Also,please share the full code of your webjobs (I mean from the inital step `public static async Task Run`)

Comment: It looks like your WebJob is configured to point to a storage account that isn’t general purpose. I know that sounds obvious, but it seems to me that you’re confusing  the *storage account* that’s configured for a WebJob with the Azure SQL database your custom WebJob code is connecting to. Look for `AzureWebJobsStorage` et al in your app settings and confirm that this is pointing at a general purpose storage account.

Comment: @KirkLarkin You are right. The "main" storage account for my Web App is blob type. And that's why the jobs were complaining. I also haven't done due diligence with RTFSC (Read The Fine Source Code), And in the Job's app config file the two connection strings for the storage accounts (`AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `AzureWebJobsStorage`) were blank. I filled them with the same conn. string and that solved it. Should I write my answer or you'd like to and I can accept it?

Comment: @Jayendran I tried to add extra attention to catch exception, log it and re-throw it. But after a while I realized that the error message I was getting was actually well localized and I should have taken it seriously and investigate it.

Comment: I think it'll be better if you write up your comment as the answer given that it's more specific to your problem and the solution you came up with. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Storage account is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS'. Supported types are 'General Purpose'?

It seems that you are use the [blob storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction#blob-storage-accounts) with Azure webjob. Please have to try to change  AzureWebJobsStorageconnection string another General Purpose [storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction#general-purpose-storage-accounts) connection.

[image]

---

Additionally fill the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection strings with the General Purpose storage account's connection string at the beginning of your `app.settings` of your WebJob.